# Is it possible to group results together after, well, grouping them together?

Tags: php, mysql

Table Structure 1 (clockins):
date | timein | timeout | jobcode | jobrate | employeeid

Table Structure 2 (jobdesc):
jobcode | jobdescription

So I have a query that does:

```
SELECT
    jd.jobdescription,
    ci.employeeid,
    ci.jobcode,
    SUM(timestampdiff(minute,ci.timein,ci.timeout) / 60) * ci.jobrate
FROM clockins ci
RIGHT JOIN jobdesc jd ON ci.jobcode = jd.jobcode
WHERE ci.date BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND '0000-00-00'
AND jobrate < 100 /* need this to distinguish salaried employees */ 
GROUP BY `jobcode` , `employeeid`
```

This outputs data like:

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIyde.png)

I am sure there must be a better way to accomplish this, but this way separates it out which is important because each job role might have different employees with different job rates. So what I need is a way to for lack of a better term "re-group" them after getting to this point in either mysql or php OR if you have suggestion on how to just do the query better too, that'd be just fine with me. I tried to find this but I couldn't quite come across an answer that would fit this situation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: whats the 'new' desired output?

Comment: I would like to see all the data grouped by jobdescription. Instead of 3 records for “Job Type 2” just one record, but still preserve the correct math for the timestampdiff column. I have tried this other ways and end up with incorrect math because when multiplying the timestampdiff by jobrate it’s only performing the equation on the first instance of jobrate. Which does not account for varying jobrates. Sorry I know this is convoluted, thanks for any help.

Comment: takie a single job, there are 3 timestamp diffs what one did you want to show?

Comment: I don't need to show one specific timestampdiff, I need to sum the timestampdiffs. I am sure I am doing a terrible job explaining maybe these pictures can help.

Here is what I am getting now:
      [link](https://imgur.com/gBCf9qm)

This is what I would like:
     [link](https://imgur.com/np0GU4y)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting colleagues help solving this. Just in case anyone else was looking for something similar here's how it's done in PHP:

```
<?php
$laborTotals = array();
$totalLaborDollars= 0;
$laborTotals[$laborAnalysis['jobcode']]['jobcode'] = $laborAnalysis['jobrole'];
    $laborTotals[$laborAnalysis['jobcode']]['jobdescription'] = $laborAnalysis['jobdescription'];
    $laborTotals[$laborAnalysis['jobcode']]['totalsalary'] += $laborAnalysis['totalsalary'];

}

foreach ($laborTotals as $labor) { 
    $html .= '  <tr>';
    $html .= '    <td class="gridData">' . $labor['jobcode'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '    <td class="gridData">' . $labor['jobdescription'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '    <td class="gridData txtLeft"><b>$</b>' . number_format($labor['totalsalary'], 2, '.', ',') . '</td>';
    $totalLaborDollars+=$labor['totalsalary'];
}

?>
```