# Hide Items with Same Name in Loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, pdo, while-loop

I want to only display an item once in my PHP loop. So if there's multiple values which are the same in `$item['name']`, it should only display it 1 time.

This is my loop:

```
                    <?php
                    while ($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                            <h5><?php echo $item['name']; ?></h5>
                            <h3><?php echo $item['displayname']; ?></h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo $item['downloadurl']; ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Download</a>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

But I have no idea how I would hide the other items with the same name. I also can't find any info about this on Google (or I'm using the wrong search terms?). Hope someone got a suggestion for me!

Comment: why can't you just keep an array of what you've already looped through and only echo if !in_array()

Comment: I see in many answers with `in_array`, I would suggest to use:

``` if (isset($u[$item['name']]) {
    continue;
}
$u[$item['name']] = 1;
```

it will increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=array();
foreach ($item['name'] as $i) {
    if (!in_array($i, $array)) {
        $array[] = $i;
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Produce your prepared statement $stmt here...

// The list of unique item names.
$itemNames = array();

// The list of items to be displayed on screen.
$displayItems = array();

while ($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $itemName = $item['name'];

    if (!in_array($itemName, $itemNames)) { // If item name not already appended to the unique names list.
        // Append item name to the unique names list.
        $itemNames[] = $itemName;

        // Append item to the list of displayable items.
        $displayItems[] = $item;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- Css/Js resources -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="items">
            <?php
            foreach ($displayItems as $item) {
                $name = $item['name'];
                $displayName = $item['displayname'];
                $downloadUrl = $item['downloadurl'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                    <h5>
                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <h3>
                        <?php echo $displayName; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <a href="<?php echo $downloadUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                        Download
                    </a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Note**:

I always maintain the code responsible for db data access on the upper part of the page. So, for example, if I need to fetch data from db, I save it into arrays. Later, in order to bring that data in html constructs, I work just with them, without having to mix data access commands like

```
while ($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {...}
```

with html code. Therefore gaining (highly) increased code readability. When you create a lot of files in this way, the advantages will become obvious.
There are also (rare) disadvantages though, like the one arised here: in order to avoid mixing the db codes with the html code, I had to apply an extra array iteration: the one for building the `$displayItems` array.

---

Otherwise, if you want to use your approach, then the solution would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- Css/Js resources -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="items">
            <?php
            // Produce your prepared statement $stmt here...

            // The list of unique item names.
            $itemNames = array();

            while ($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $name = $item['name'];

                if (!in_array($name, $itemNames)) { // If item name not already appended to the unique names list.
                    // Append item name to the unique names list.
                    $itemNames[] = $name;

                    $displayName = $item['displayname'];
                    $downloadUrl = $item['downloadurl'];
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                        <h5>
                            <?php echo $name; ?>
                        </h5>
                        <h3>
                            <?php echo $displayName; ?>
                        </h3>
                        <a href="<?php echo $downloadUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                            Download
                        </a>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577302/is-it-possible-to-group-results-together-after-well-grouping-them-together) If I am understanding correctly, I think you are trying to do the same thing I was.

Answer (score 0):

Other people gave you good solutions to solve your issue, but this thing is going to cost you more processing time through your app run-time.
You can use DISTINCT keyword in your sql select query so automatically you will get the name just once.

Chick this tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Do you mean to run an "auxiliary" sql query to fetch only the distinct names prior to running the sql query for fetching the items? Thanks.

Comment: Yea, something like this.